# How to import a dockerized common module from a different docker in python

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have a python file containing generic functions named `utils.py` and another set of programs say, `pgm1.py`, `pgm2.py`, `pgm3.py` which `imports` `utils.py` and invokes it's functions eg: `utils.send_email()`, `utils.time_convert()` etc..

My requirement is to dockerize utils, pgm1, pgm2, and pgm3 in different containers and still be able to access the generic functions.

Can someone tell me how this can be achieved

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the dependency using the normal Python packaging tools (in your `setup.cfg` file, or using a tool like Pipfile or Poetry) and import it into each image.

A Docker image contains an *application*, plus *all* of its dependencies.  A container can't access the files, libraries, or applications in other containers.  So it doesn't make sense to have "a container of generic functions" that's not running an application, and you can't "import libraries from another container"; since the filesystems are isolated from each other, one container can't access the `*.py` files in another.

---

As you've described the problem, you're dealing with a small number of individual files, and the size of the Python interpreter will be much larger than any individual script.  In this case it's fine to create an image that includes all of them

```sh
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY ./ ./

CMD ["./pgm1.py"] # for example; do not use ENTRYPOINT here
```

You can then easily override that `CMD` when you run the container to select a different program.

```sh
docker run -d --name program-1 my-image ./pgm1.py
docker run -d --name program-2 my-image ./pgm2.py
```